# Фокусировка поля после загрузки картинки

Tags: предложение, дизайн, редактор, загрузка-изображения

Загрузка картинки - дело не мгновенное, и пока она грузится, мне может захотеться написать заголовок или поставить метки. Проблема в том, что после загрузки картинки курсор автоматически перемещается на написание alt'а этой картики, а другое поле остаётся недописанным. Предлагаю так не делать, но **только если** курсор находится в другом текстовом поле. В принципе можно ещё какой-нибудь debounce повесить от последнего действия пользователя.